# How to create a file with Chinese characters in the name by Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, unicode, character

The problem is:

```
echo HiWorld > c:\filename.txt
```

`filename` is Chinese.

How to do that?

Comment: _Save the batch file in UTF-8 without Byte Order Mark_: Windows native `notepad` can't do it; use e.g. _free_ [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). As for error message `The system cannot write to the specified device`: please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46129875/3439404) and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

1. **Save** your batch file in `UTF-8` **without** [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).
2. **Run** that  batch file in **code page `65001`** (i.e. [`UTF-8` in Windows `cmd` environment](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)).

**Sample batch file**:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
dir /B "D:\bat\UnASCII Names\CJK (中文(繁體))"
echo HiWorld>"D:\bat\UnASCII Names\CJK (中文(繁體))\中文(繁體).txt"
dir /B "D:\bat\UnASCII Names\CJK (中文(繁體))"
type "D:\bat\UnASCII Names\CJK (中文(繁體))\中文(繁體).txt"
```

**Output** (you can see that may default code page is `852`; your one could be different):

```
==> chcp
Active code page: 852

==> D:\bat\SO\46129875.bat
File Not Found
The system cannot find the path specified.
File Not Found
The system cannot find the path specified.

==> chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

==> D:\bat\SO\46129875.bat
中文(繁體).txt
HiWorld

==>
```

**Edit**: script updated according to worthwhile [Eryksun's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46129875/how-to-create-a-file-with-chinese-characters-in-the-name-by-windows-batch-file/46130549?noredirect=1#comment79227061_46130549)

```
@:: How to create a file with Chinese characters in the name by Windows batch file? 
@:: this file must be saved in `UTF-8` encoding, preferably without Byte Order Mark
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
:: save the active code page number parsing "Active code page: NNN" output from CHCP
for /F "tokens=4" %%G in ('chcp') do set "_chcp=%%G"
:: change the active console code page to UTF-8 
>NUL chcp 65001
:: DEBUGGING: erase all .TXT files from target folder 
>NUL 2>&1 del "D:\bat\UnASCII Names\CJK (中文(繁體))\*.txt"
:: create a file with Chinese characters in the name inside target folder 
echo HiWorld>"D:\bat\UnASCII Names\CJK (中文(繁體))\中文(繁體).txt"
echo Hi All>>"D:\bat\UnASCII Names\CJK (中文(繁體))\中文(繁體).txt"
:: DEBUGGING: show the name of created file
dir /B "D:\bat\UnASCII Names\CJK (中文(繁體))"
:: DEBUGGING: show the content of created file
type "D:\bat\UnASCII Names\CJK (中文(繁體))\中文(繁體).txt"
:: change the active console code page back to previously saved value 
>NUL chcp %_chcp%
```

**Output**

```
==> chcp
Active code page: 852

==> D:\bat\SO\46129875.bat
中文(繁體).txt
HiWorld
Hi All

==> chcp
Active code page: 852

==>
```

Comment: CMD decodes a batch file line by line, so you can actually switch to 65001 temporarily in the script and then switch back to the previous codepage. That said, if the batch file is executed without a console (i.e. created as a `DETACHED_PROCESS`), then CMD defaults to the ANSI codepage (not OEM), so a script that needs another codepage has to be run with a console -- at least hidden or without a window.

Comment: Thanks, How to 'Save the batch file in UTF-8 -without Byte Order Mark'-? because I get this message after running the first line of my batch: 'ي╗┐' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.' of course, I added '&cls' as the first line to eliminate the message. I use notepad for editing batch files.  Should I remove the Byte Order Mark? how?

Comment: Also, sometimes I get this error message: "echo HiWorld 1>The system cannot write to the specified device." but by inserting quotation marks around file name it disappeared. ofcourse, I had added a ' >nul ' at the end of line.

Comment: @cya, use an editor such as Notepad++ to write UTF-8 without a BOM. Otherwise you can rewrite the file at the command line. For example: `(chcp 65001 >nul) && (>script_nobom.bat echo @ECHO OFF) && (for /f "skip=1 delims=" %a in ('type script.bat') do @(>>script_nobom.bat echo %a))`. I'm not a batch expert, so someone else can probably write it better.

Comment: thanks for your patience. question1) in the following batch: @echo off chcp 65001 for /R c:\test\ %%f in (*.txt) do ( call :sub "%%f" ) chcp 720 pause exit :sub echo %1 exit /b . . it generates "can not write to the specified ddevice". I found that the error is for the 4th line: call :sub "%%f" -----> it takes the "%%f" as a redirection. when I change the "%%f" with a plain text like abcd or.... it runs without error. even I double quoted the %%f but still it generates the error!  This error appears only when I use the chcp 65001 code line. if I remove that line, everything works good!!

Comment: question2) in Notepad++ how to create my file in utf-8 and also remove bom?